# Angular Material Table: Dynamically add background color and button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Mat Table as following. The Request is that background color and button should be add dynamically at 'the first row of each TYPE'.

So I have to identify which row is the first row per type. I know it can be done by loop the data and do something in the ts. But I'm wondering if there is any cleaner way to do this? Thank you!

```js
let proArr : Product[] = [{type:'A', name:'name1', amount: 1},{type:'A', name:'name2', amount: 2},{type:'A', name:'name3', amount: 3},{type:'B', name:'name4', amount: 4},xxxx]
let dataSouce : MatTableDataSource<Product> = proArr;
```

[image]